# Space homeomorphic to $n$-manifold is an $n$-manifold

Tags: general-topology

Is it true, that if a topological space is homeomorphic to a $n$-manifold it is itself a $n$-manifold? I think, this should be true, but somehow I am unable to prove this.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Dimensionality), being an $n$-manifold is a topological property. All you need now is a proof

Comment: @IrregularUser Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which property are you unable to prove? Show us what you've done so far, and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being locally Euclidean, like being Hausdorff and second countable, is a topological property. Indeed, if $f:X \to M$ is a homeomorphism from a space $X$ to a manifold $M$, and $x \in X$ is any point, then we may find a coordinate system about $x$ by pulling back the coordinate system about $f(x) \in M$. (Since $M$ is a manifold, there is a homeomorphism $\phi$ from an open set $U$ containing $f(x)$ to an open subset of some Euclidean space. Then the restriction of the homeomorphism $\phi \circ f$ to the open neighborhood $f^{-1}(U)$ of $x$ gives us the sought after coordinate map.)